# How to set environment variable in systemd service?

Tags: systemd

I have an [Arch Linux system with systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd) and I've created my own service. The configuration service at `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service` looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Daemon

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/myforegroundcmd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now I want to have an environment variable set for the `/bin/myforegroundcmd`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 498, accepted):

Times change and so do best practices.

[The *current*](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines) best way to do this is to run `systemctl edit myservice`, which will create an override file for you or let you edit an existing one.

In normal installations this will create a directory `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service.d`, and inside that directory create a file whose name ends in `.conf` (typically, `override.conf`), and in this file you can add to or override any part of the unit shipped by the distribution.

For instance, in a file `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service.d/myenv.conf`:

```ini
[Service]
Environment="SECRET=pGNqduRFkB4K9C2vijOmUDa2kPtUhArN"
Environment="ANOTHER_SECRET=JP8YLOc2bsNlrGuD6LVTq7L36obpjzxd"
```

Also note that if the directory exists and is empty, your service will be disabled! If you don't intend to put something in the directory, ensure that it does not exist.

---

For reference, the old way was:

[The recommended way](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Systemd#EnvironmentFiles_and_support_for_.2Fetc.2Fsysconfig_files) to do this is to create a file `/etc/sysconfig/myservice` which contains your variables, and then load them with `EnvironmentFile`.

For complete details, see Fedora's documentation on [how to write a systemd script](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Systemd).

Comment: I guess the `sysconfig` path is specific to Fedora but the question is about Arch Linux. The answer by paluh is more interesting I think

Comment: @LudovicKuty systemd is virtually identical across distributions that use it.

Comment: `/etc/sysconfig` is Fedora-specific. AFAIR Arch Linux was pushing for having the config files somewhere package-specific rather in `/etc` rather than that Fedora-specific location. Like `/etc/myservice.conf`, though using extra file doesn't seem the right way here.

Comment: I don't remember exactly where Arch keeps these files, but I think it's `/etc/conf.d`. Some inspection of existing unit files should reveal the directory it uses.

Comment: No, no, no. /etc/sysconfig is not recomended. It is discouraged, along with /etc/default/* from debian, because they are pointless, and the names are meaningless and make sense only for backwards compatibility reasons (all of /etc is about configuration of the system, not just /etc/sysconfig, and /etc/defaults is for overrides, not the defaults). Just put the definitions directly in the unit file, or if it is not possible, in an enviornment file that has a package specific location (like Michał's comment suggests).

Comment: Can you give an example of how the contents of an EnvironmentFile actually looks like?

Comment: @FrederickNord It's just variable=value pairs, such as `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings`, one per line.

Comment: If I create my own blah.service to run my own `blah` service, can I also use the `/etc/systemd/system/blah.service.d/blah.conf` file to pass `Environment=` stuff to my `blah` service?

Comment: Don't use `Environment=` to pass secrets like passwords. See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/910655/1143) for details.

Comment: Documentation for drop-in files is here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html (search in page for 'drop-in')

Comment: I like this answer because it gets to the point systemctl edit myservice, as opposed to the documentation which shows a plethora of ways to do it leaving me confused as how to proceed.

Comment: Drop-in files aren't ideal for all cases. if you're re-using a certain value all over the place such as a certain directory or user ID, extracting it into an environment variable is an elegant solution. Solving this using drop-in files means duplicating and editing the entire service definition.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The linked document as "the current best way" does not give any recommendations or preferences on using `Environment` over `EnvironmentFile`. And given the `Environment=`'s values being visible to all with `systemctl show`, as explained in @DonKirby's answer, it seems to me that `EnvironmentFile` is much better.

Comment: Curious, is there a way to unset environment variable, eg. `Environment=EV=`? This one just clears the value, but can we remove defined variable completely?

Answer (score 133):

The answer depends on whether the variable is supposed to be constant (that is, not supposed to be modified by user getting the unit) or variable (supposed to be set by the user).

Since it's your local unit, the boundary is quite blurry and either way would work. However, if you started to distribute it and it would end up in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`, this would become important.

## Constant value

If the value doesn't need to change per instance, the preferred way would be to place it as `Environment=`, directly in the unit file:

```sh
[Unit]
Description=My Daemon

[Service]
Environment="FOO=bar baz"
ExecStart=/bin/myforegroundcmd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The advantage of that is that the variable is kept in a single file with the unit. Therefore, the unit file is easier to move between systems.

## Variable value

However, the above solution doesn't work well when sysadmin is supposed to change the value of the environment variable locally. More specifically, the new value would need to be set every time the unit file is updated.

For this case, an extra file is to be used. How — usually depends on the distribution policy.

One particularly interesting solution is to use `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service.d` directory. Unlike other solutions, this directory is supported by systemd itself and therefore comes with no distribution-specific paths.

In this case, you place a file like `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service.d/local.conf` that adds the missing parts of unit file:

```sh
[Service]
Environment="FOO=bar baz"
```

Afterwards, systemd merges the two files when starting the service (remember to `systemctl daemon-reload` after changing either of them). And since this path is used directly by systemd, you don't use `EnvironmentFile=` for this.

If the value is supposed to be changed only on some of the affected systems, you may combine both solutions, providing a default directly in the unit and a local override in the other file.

Comment: `systemctl daemon-reload` is the command to reload systemd

Comment: `EnvironmentFile=` is better when the values are secrets like passwords. See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/910655/1143) for details.

Comment: Structuring the question around "Constant" vs "Changeable" seems to me to miss the point, as that is really just an explanation of unit overrides. The main question is whether to specify the values with `Environment=` directly in the unit, or use `EnvironmentFile=` that points to the file containing the variable assignments.

Answer (score 73):

The answers by [Michael](https://serverfault.com/a/413408/1143) and [Michał](https://serverfault.com/a/590732/1143) are helpful and answer the original question of how to set an environment variable for a systemd service. However, one [common use](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-keep-your-secret-keys-safe-secure-8b1a7877d69c) for environment variables is to configure sensitive data like passwords in a place that won't accidentally get committed to source control with your application's code.

If that's why you want to pass an environment variable to your service, **do not** use `Environment=` in the unit configuration file. Use [`EnvironmentFile=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment) and point it to another configuration file that is only readable by the service account (and users with root access).

The details of the unit configuration file are visible to any user with this command:

```
systemctl show my_service
```

I put a configuration file at `/etc/my_service/my_service.conf` and put my secrets in there:

```
MY_SECRET=correcthorsebatterystaple
STARFLEET_SECRET=412Mark80
```

Then in my service unit file, I used `EnvironmentFile=`:

```
[Unit]
Description=my_service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /path/to/my_service.py
EnvironmentFile=/etc/my_service/my_service.conf
User=myservice

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I checked that `ps auxe` can't see those environment variables, and other users don't have access to `/proc/*/environ`. Check on your own system, of course.

Comment: Why is using Environment= for secrets bad?

Comment: As I said, `systemctl show my_service` will show the unit configuration file contents to any user, including `Environment=`. Try it out.

Comment: Yes. Even the content in `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service.d/override.conf`, generated by `systemctl edit myservice`, will be shown by `systemctl show myservice`.

Comment: What is the format of environment files? Google says space separated list. Can you use newlines instead like a normal .env file that I'm used to?

Comment: I added a link to the documentation, @KevinWheeler. `Environment=` is space delimited, but `EnvironmentFile=` is newline delimited.

Answer (score 64):

http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd.exec.html#Environment= - you have two options (one already pointed by Michael):

```
Environment=
```

and

```
EnvironmentFile=
```

Comment: Just leaving this here: If you decide to use EnviromentFile= make sure your file does not contain 'export VARIABLE=VALUE' statements but just the 'VARIABLE=VALUE' basic statements to make it work. Thought it might possibly help someone out.

Comment: This is helpful if you're converting from sysvinit's `/etc/default/` to systemd.

Answer (score 11):

Michael gave one clean solution but I wanted to get updated env variable from script. 
Unfortunately executing bash commands is not possible in systemd unit file. Fortunately you can trigger bash inside ExecStart:

http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=systemd.service&ampsect=5

> Note that this setting does not directly support shell command lines. If shell command lines are to be used they need to be passed explicitly to a shell implementation of some kind.

Example in our case is then:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "ENV=`script`; /bin/myforegroundcmd"
```

Comment: This won't work for multiple reasons (unless it's a "one-shot" service, which is rather pointless). I managed to get the following to work:
`/bin/bash -a -c 'source /etc/sysconfig/whatever && exec whatever-program'` . The `-a` ensures the environment is exported to the sub-process (unless you want to prefix all variables in `whatever` with `export` )

Comment: why it won't work? It should always trigger entire command which includes executing the script, ain't it?

Comment: Maybe `ExecStart=/usr/bin/env ENV=script /bin/myforegroundcmd` is a little better solution in this case.

Comment: @Otheus: Great answer, saved by day when I had to create a Tomcat 8 Unit file.

Comment: There IS a way to execute a bash command "in" a systemd service file. See this link: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html

Comment: @MarkLakata sadly your link is gone since RedHat subsumed **CoreOS**. I've tried to search for that information on RedHat's documentation portal, but to no avail — Microsoft's own documentation portal is a paradise compared to RedHat's :-P

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn I found a back up of that page. 
 https://web.archive.org/web/20190716112314/https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html

Answer (score 11):

Don't use Environment= or EnvironmentFile= for credentials / secrets.

Per https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment

You should use `LoadCredential=, LoadCredentialEncrypted= or SetCredentialEncrypted=`

> Note that environment variables are not suitable for passing secrets (such as passwords, key material, …) to service processes. Environment variables set for a unit are exposed to unprivileged clients via D-Bus IPC, and generally not understood as being data that requires protection. Moreover, environment variables are propagated down the process tree, including across security boundaries (such as setuid/setgid executables), and hence might leak to processes that should not have access to the secret data. Use LoadCredential=, LoadCredentialEncrypted= or SetCredentialEncrypted= (see below) to pass data to unit processes securely.