# Re-run command on end

Tags: command-line-interface

I have binary file that I run like
`env SOME_VARS=some_values ./my_binary`

Is there a way that when this execution ends (be it that it ends correctly or it crashes or it gets killed, whatever), it gets started again with the same environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify platform, I will assume Linux.  In which case [the Restart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34333783/4735500) [and Environment](https://serverfault.com/a/590732/241174) options of a systemd service unit could work nicely. These can be defined in user specific units so it can be run as a non privileged user.