# How do I set enviromental varialbes for my ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, django, environment-variables, digital-ocean

I have a ubuntu server deployed at digitalocean with gunicorn and nginx to host my django project.
Now I want to save my secret key in an env. var. . I searched in the internet and I found that I have to modify a file called `.bash_profile` but I don't have this file in my home directory.
What should I do?

Thx for your help and stay healthy!

Comment: Create the file with a text editor of your choice.

Comment: Is this good practice?

Comment: But if I create it .profile won't be read anymore?!

Comment: bash reads both `.profile` and `.bash_profile`. Both are however not ideal locations to set environment variables for a service, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the file with a text editor of your choice.

`~/.bash_profile` would however not be an ideal location for this, because it's only read by bash. There are better places to set the environment variables. `~/.profile` Is read by other shells as well, but those files are only read when the shell is called as a login shell. When you run an application as a service this is usually not the case.

Ideally you would [configure an environment file in your service definition](https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service) if your service is run by systemd, or set it in the startup script of your service if you are using another init system.

Comment: There is no way to answer that without knowing what you are running and how you are starting it.