# Jenkins not detecting java on ubuntu, how to fix that?

Tags: ubuntu, java, jenkins

Downloaded adopt [openjdk](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u282-b08/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_8u282b08.tar.gz) version 8 and extracted on the machine.
Set the path variable and JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment and /etc/bash.rc also.

```
JAVA_HOME="/home/adminuser/Desktop/jdk8u282-b08"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/adminuser/Desktop/jdk8u282-b08/bin"
```

> #both are working
>
> ```
> java -version
>
> type -p java
> ```

But when I started jenkins service, it is not detecting the java.
Can you please suggest.
Installing from apt is not an feasible option as we need this specific java version for project.

Comment: How do you start the service?

Comment: sudo systemctl start jenkins

Comment: Be aware, systemd ignores environment variables. You should update the service file

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service