# Environment Variable set in systemd service file not set

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I have the problem than when I start my service a environment variable I have set in the service file is not set.
The Service file is as follows

```
[Unit]
Description=<DESCRPITON>
After=podman.socket
Requires=podman.socket


[Service]
Environment=DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/$UID/podman/podman.sock
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/<BINARY_NAME>
Restart=always
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
User=<USER>


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I set the environment variable with `systemctl --user set-environment DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/$UID/podman/podman.sock` then it works. But not when the system is reboot as for some reason the information is lost.

I have to run the service under as the user and under the user, so it is run with `systemctl enable --now serivce-name.service`.

I have looked at [How to set environment variable in systemd service?](https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service) but could not find a solution from here.
I was thinking about adding an configuraiton file, it just seems a little to much for a single Env variable.

This is running on Fedora and RedHat (8.8) if it is relevant.

Comment: look with `systemctl show mariadb.service`